# How do I populate an href string using XSLT?

Tags: web-applications, xslt-1.0

I am trying to generate a relative URL with a complex query string using XSLT 1.0 stylesheets (processed by the web browser).

```
<xsl:variable name="queryLn">sql</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="queryName">ask</xsl:variable>
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:text>path?action=exec&queryLn=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$queryLn" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="$queryName" />
</a>
```

I have altered how the variables get assigned for simplicity. In the real code, they get assigned similar values from the XML being transformed. I want the resulting document to contain this:

```
<a href="path?action=exec&queryLn=sql>ask</a>
```

Chrome Browswer gives me an error message like `error on line XX at column YY: EntityRef: expecting ';'`, where XX and YY refer to immediately after the `<xsl:text>` opening tag. I've tried adding a `disable-output-escaping="yes"` attribute to the `<xsl:text>` element, but that doesn't have any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<a href="path?action=exec&amp;queryLn={$queryLn}"><xsl:value-of select="$queryName"/></a>
```

**Your code has these problems**:

1. Unescaped `&` -- must be `&amp;`.
2. Unnecessary `<xsl:attribute>` -- it is recommended that one uses **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** -s (Attribute - Value Templates) always when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox gave a much more useful error message that pointed me in the right direction.

It turns out this was invalid XML. `&` needed to be `&amp;`.